# How to design a tree like data structure in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, tree

I have a entity called "Category" and a entity called "item". Category may have one or more sub categories or have one or more items.

Here is what I designed.

[image]

But I have a special requirement. If the category has items, it won't have sub-categories. I don't know how to do this in my model design.

Any suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to model this in the data model. You have to simply check for items before you create the subcategory.

Also, when deleting items, check if they leave any empty categories with (also empty) subcategories.

Comment: Not surprise at the answer because I tried very hard and found no ways to do that in model editor.So have to do that manually in my code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ZhouHao would you give an example how do you solved your problem?

Comment: Just override `willSave()` and similar functions of your managed objects and put the logic there.